# Can I INSERT into table while table is being TRUNCATEd?

Tags: sql, oracle, truncate

I have a a SYSTEM table AUD$ where every user's action is written to (AUDIT select, insert, update, ...). This table has 100 million records. I decided to truncate the table (which will take few minutes i guess) because we no longer need this data.

But every time a user logs in to the Database, a record in this table AUD$ gets created.

So my question is : does INSERT (if user logs in to database) works during the TRUNCATE table ?

Comment: The truncate should lock the table and not allow inserts during the process.

Comment: If you are licensed for it, partitioning would be useful here. You could truncate old partitions without affecting the current one.

Comment: Are you asking the right question? The way Oracle is built, if an INSERT statement (to your audit table) is issued when a user logs on, and the table is locked due to your TRUNCATE operation, what should happen is that the INSERT will have to wait for the lock to be released. Perhaps logging on will also have to wait for the same thing (depending on how you structured the whole thing). Does that constitute "not working" according to your definition? Meaning, having to wait till the lock is released? Some may view that as "working exactly as it should be".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has a package called DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT that can (and should) be used to manage your audit table, which is the proper way to reduce the size if AUD$. It can be used to manage OS level auditing as well, if you're writing those files out. Here's an example of moving the AUD$ table to its own tablespace, and setting up auditing management.

Create a dedicated audit tablespace

```
CREATE TABLESPACE AUDAUX DATAFILE '/u01/oracle/oradata/<DB_NAME>/audaux01.dbf'
SIZE 25M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10m MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
```

Move the sys.aud$ table to the new tablespace

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
 DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.SET_AUDIT_TRAIL_LOCATION(
  AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE            => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_AUD_STD, 
  AUDIT_TRAIL_LOCATION_VALUE  => 'AUDAUX');
END;
/
```

Set the required parameters, bounce the database if needed

```
audit_trail='DB,EXTENDED'
audit_sys_operations=true
```

Initialize the cleanup operation

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
 DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.INIT_CLEANUP(
  AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE            => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_AUD_STD,
  DEFAULT_CLEANUP_INTERVAL    => 12 );
END;
/
```

Verify that cleanup is initialized

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
 IF 
   DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.IS_CLEANUP_INITIALIZED(DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_AUD_STD)
 THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AUD$ is initialized for clean-up');
 ELSE
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AUD$ is not initialized for clean-up.');
 END IF;
END;
/
```

Create a purge job

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
  DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.CREATE_PURGE_JOB (
   AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE            => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_AUD_STD, 
   AUDIT_TRAIL_PURGE_INTERVAL  => 12,
   AUDIT_TRAIL_PURGE_NAME      => 'Standard_Audit_Trail_Purge',
   USE_LAST_ARCH_TIMESTAMP     => FALSE );
END;
/
```

Drop purge job example

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
  DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.DROP_PURGE_JOB (
   AUDIT_TRAIL_PURGE_NAME      => 'DB_AUDIT_TRAIL_PURGE');
END;
/
```